# How to achieve thread safety while looking up database in spring service

Tags: spring-boot

I am running into a thread safety issue when i made two api calls with same id at sametime.
In the service below both threads are evaluating (payment == null) to true and as a result saving the object twice. Leading to duplicate payment records.
One way i can make this thread safe is by making the service method "synchronized". Just want to check with community to see if there is a better way to handle this ?

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/ng-api")
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class IpasNGController {

    @Autowired
    NgService ngService;

    @PutMapping(path = "/create-cart")
    public ResponseEntity<AbstractngServiceResponse> createCart(@RequestBody @Valid NGDto ngDto) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ngService.createNGCart(ngDto.getId()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}



@Service
public class NgServiceImpl extends AbstractExternalServiceHandler implements NgService {
 public Payment getPaymentInformation(BigInteger id) {
     Payment payment = paymentRepository.findPaymentById(id);
     if (payment == null) {
         payment = paymentBuilder.save(id, additionalInfoToBuildPaymentObject);
     }
     return payment;
 }
```